# Shourcut line on equation in latex

Tags: equations

who is know how I can make this line like bellow?[image]

or like.

Comment: see the `cancel` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cancel` package can be used for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor,cancel}
\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \biggl(\frac{8x-2}{\cancel{18}}-\frac{x-2}{\cancel{18}}\biggr) \cdot \cancel{18} &= \frac{21}{\cancel{18}} \cdot \cancel{18}
        \\
        8x - \bcancel{2} - x + \bcancel{2} &= 21
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX code associated with the image would be:

```
\begin{align*}
   ( \frac{8x - 2}{{\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Black} 18}}}} - \frac{x - 2}{{\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Black} 18}}}} ) \times {\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Blue} 18}}} = \frac{21}{{\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Black} 18}}}} \times {\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Blue} 18}}}\\
   8x - 2 - ( x - 2 ) = 21\\
   8x - {\color{Red} \bcancel{{\color{Black} 2}}} - x + {\color{Red} \bcancel{{\color{Black} 2}}} = 21\\
\end{align*}
```

[image: your picture]

The used commands are:

- `\bcancel{}` strikes through the content from top left to bottom right
- `\cancel{}` strikes through the content from bottom left to top right
- `{\color{add color} {}}` gives the contained objects the color
- `\frac{}{}` creates a fraction bar
- `\times` creates the symbol of the cross product
- `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` contains a alignmend
- `\\` implies a line break

---

Personally, however, I would prefer this:

```
    \begin{align*}
       \left( \frac{8 \cdot x - 2}{{\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Black} 18}}}} - \frac{x - 2}{{\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Black} 18}}}} \right) \cdot {\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Blue} 18}}} &= \frac{21}{{\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Black} 18}}}} \cdot {\color{Red} \cancel{{\color{Blue} 18}}}\\
       8 \cdot x - 2 - \left( x - 2 \right) &= 21\\
       8 \cdot x - {\color{Red} \bcancel{{\color{Black} 2}}} - x + {\color{Red} \bcancel{{\color{Black} 2}}} &= 21\\
\end{align*}
```

[image: my idia]

The new used commands are:

- `&` aligns
- `\cdot` creates a center dot
- `\left( \right)` creates brackets that are as big as their content